# Green-Tao's "Polylogarithmic bound for $r_4(N)$"

Tags: analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, additive-combinatorics, fourier-transform

On P.23 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.01703.pdf, they seemed to suggest that by the non-negativity of $\psi\big(\frac{k}{N}\big)$ for all $k$,
$$
K_N(\xi_0 n)\left[1-\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi\xi_0 n}{p}\bigg)\right]=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}e_p(kn)\left(\psi(k/N)-\frac{\psi\big(\frac{k-1}{N}\big)+\psi\big(\frac{k+1}{N}\big)}{2}\right)$$
and $$
\psi(k/N)-\frac{\psi\big(\frac{k-1}{N}\big)+\psi\big(\frac{k+1}{N}\big)}{2}\ll\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{j=-8}^{8}\psi\left(\frac{k}{N}-\frac{j}{4}\right)
$$
imply
$$
K_N(\xi_0 n)\left[1-\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi\xi_0 n}{p}\bigg)\right]\ll\frac{1}{N^2}K_N(\xi_0 n)
$$
I fail to see why it is obvious, I would imagine that since $\cos\big(\frac{2\pi kn}{p}\big)$ can take both positive and negative value it would make the conclusion less obvious. Any hint of why their claim is true would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We are not claiming this pointwise estimate; instead we are claiming the integrated estimate in which both sides are averaged against $\prod_{\xi \in S \backslash \xi_0} K_N(\xi n)$.  This is accomplished by expanding both sides into Fourier coefficients and using the facts previously mentioned.

Comment: Got it. I misunderstood. Thanks!